# Equivalence for upper semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Well, the definition of upper semicontinuity that I know is (1)

> 1. $F:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is upper semicontinuous at $x_0\in X$ if for all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $x\in X\cap(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\Rightarrow f(x)< f(x_0)+\varepsilon$
> 2. For $x_0\in X$, $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq f(x_0)$

I want to prove $(1)\Leftrightarrow (2)$
This is what I've tried:

- $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$:
  Let $L=\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)$. By definition of infimum, given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $\sup\{f(x):X\cap |x-x_0|<\delta\}<L + \varepsilon$, then, for this $\delta$, we have $X\cap |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow f(x)< L+\varepsilon \leq f(x_0)+\varepsilon$
- $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$:
  Given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ s.t. $X\cap |x-x_0|<\delta\Rightarrow  f(x)<f(x_0)+\varepsilon \Rightarrow  \sup\{f(x):X\cap|x-x_0|<\delta\}\leq f(x_0)+\varepsilon.$ By definition of infimum, $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq \sup\{f(x):X\cap|x-x_0|<\delta\}\leq f(x_0)+\varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary. Hence $\limsup_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq f(x_0)$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Here's an attempt at an intuitive statement. For $f$ to be continuous at $x_0$ means (roughly speaking) that if $x \approx x_0$ then $f(x) \approx f(x_0)$. For $f$ to be upper semicontinuous at $x_0$ means (roughly speaking) that if $x \approx x_0$ then $f(x) \lessapprox f(x_0)$.  (In words, $f(x)$ is less than or approximately equal to $f(x_0)$.)

Comment: It means that the function can have downwards "jumps" in the neighborhood of $x_0$ but not upwards. To see the link with the inferior limit, take the limit of your definition when $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.